# Ipython Notebook Running only as root

Tags: ipython, root, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I was trying to import a notebook in iPython(Jupyter after updating). But for some reason, I am able to import any notebook only if I run as root user. Otherwise, I get the following error for all notebooks.

> An unknown error occurred while loading this notebook. This version
>   can load notebook formats v4 or earlier. See the server log for
>   details.

iPython3 notebook is able to load the notebooks though.
Is there something that I can do to resolve this issue?

```
[W 23:04:29.100 NotebookApp] 404 GET /static/components/MathJax/config/Safe.js?rev=2.5.3 (127.0.0.1) 40.67ms referer=http://localhost:8889/notebooks/Challenges/German%20Credit%20Dataset%20Classification%20-%20Challenge%201/GermanCreditCardClassification.ipynb
[E 23:04:29.377 NotebookApp] Unhandled error in API request
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py", line 436, in wrapper
        result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 870, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 215, in result
        raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 230, in wrapper
        yielded = next(result)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/services/contents/handlers.py", line 129, in get
        path=path, type=type, format=format, content=content,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 348, in get
        model = self._notebook_model(path, content=content)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 308, in _notebook_model
        self.mark_trusted_cells(nb, path)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/services/contents/manager.py", line 447, in mark_trusted_cells
        trusted = self.notary.check_signature(nb)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 220, in check_signature
        if self.db is None:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 439, in __get__
        value = self._validate(obj, dynamic_default())
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 126, in _db_default
        db = sqlite3.connect(self.db_file, **kwargs)
    OperationalError: unable to open database file
[E 23:04:29.389 NotebookApp] {
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8", 
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch", 
      "Connection": "keep-alive", 
      "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01", 
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36", 
      "Dnt": "1", 
      "Host": "localhost:8889", 
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest", 
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8889/notebooks/Challenges/German%20Credit%20Dataset%20Classification%20-%20Challenge%201/GermanCreditCardClassification.ipynb"
    }
[E 23:04:29.390 NotebookApp] 500 GET /api/contents/Challenges/German%20Credit%20Dataset%20Classification%20-%20Challenge%201/GermanCreditCardClassification.ipynb?type=notebook&_=1449266668869 (127.0.0.1) 134.27ms referer=http://localhost:8889/notebooks/Challenges/German%20Credit%20Dataset%20Classification%20-%20Challenge%201/GermanCreditCardClassification.ipynb
```

Ipython Details
Server Information:

```
You are using Jupyter notebook.

The version of the notebook server is 4.0.2 and is running on:
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2]

Current Kernel Information:

unable to contact kernel
```

OS: Linux Mint x64 running on 3.13.0-37-generic Kernel

**Answer:**
KT.'s solution works. I think that I ran Jupyter as root the first time which caused the files to be inaccessible to non root users as mentioned by KT.

Comment: The first obvious question is: what does the server log say?

Comment: Which Python, Jupyter, OS, …?
How can I reproduce this?

Comment: @KT. Added the server log

Comment: @user1836587 Added the environment info

Comment: Same error happened to me on Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 2.7.10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, let me take a guess here.

When you ran `ipython notebook` for the first time it was under `root`. Consequently, some of the files that Jupyter uses were created as root-owned from the start. It is no surprise now that whenever you run Jupyter as a non-root user, he fails to write to those files which results in the errors that you see.

In the particular situation that you see in the log, Jupyter has problems writing to the `nbsignatures.db` SQLite database. This file should be located in Jupyter's `DATA_DIR`, which is normally something like `~/.local/share/jupyter`.

If you do not have this directory, you can find it out by running `ipython` and doing this, for example:

```
In [1]: from jupyter_core.application import JupyterApp
In [2]: JupyterApp().data_dir
Out[2]: u'/home/ubuntu/.local/share/jupyter'
```

What you need to do now is to make sure that everything in that directory is owned by the correct user, not by root. This might mean doing something like

```
# chown -R <yourusername>.<yourusername> ~/.local/share/jupyter
```

as root.

Comment: Thanks, although I don't remember having started it the first time as root, the configuration files in `~/.local/share/jupyter` indeed were root-owned, maybe generated during installation.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem. 
Attached beneath are my error message.

```
[E 19:32:53.893 NotebookApp] Unhandled error in API request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py", line 436, in wrapper
    result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 870, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 215, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 230, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/handlers.py", line 126, in get
    path=path, type=type, format=format, content=content,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 350, in get
    model = self._notebook_model(path, content=content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 310, in _notebook_model
    self.mark_trusted_cells(nb, path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/manager.py", line 447, in mark_trusted_cells
    trusted = self.notary.check_signature(nb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 220, in check_signature
    if self.db is None:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 439, in __get__
    value = self._validate(obj, dynamic_default())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 127, in _db_default
    self.init_db(db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 139, in init_db
    )""")
DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed

[E 19:32:53.895 NotebookApp] {
      "Accept-Language": "en,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.6,zh-TW;q=0.4,fr;q=0.2,es;q=0.2", 
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch", 
      "Connection": "keep-alive", 
      "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01", 
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36", 
      "Host": "localhost:8888", 
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/notebooks/trajectory_analysis.ipynb", 
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }
```

I solved it by removing a file: **nbsignatures.db**.

Because the location of Jupyter on OSX is system-dependent, first locate the file using:

```
jupyter --data-dir
```

Then, remove the **nbsignatures.db** in it.

Reference: [DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed #9293](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9293).